# Gunicorn import error

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to get a flask app to work with gunicorn.

When I do the following it works:

```
. env/bin/activate
python app.py
```

However when I do:

```
. env/bin/activate
gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8005
```

It fails to work, citing an issue with importing simplejson.  simplejson is installed both in virtualenv, and std python lib

Ok, after playing, it's simplejson that's causing the fuss.  Removing the import allows the system to run.  However simplejson is a critical element.

```
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22522] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22522] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8005 (22522)
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22522] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22527] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22527
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22527] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/flasker/killerfees/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kf import app
  File "/home/flasker/killerfees/kf/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from kf import views
  File "/home/flasker/killerfees/kf/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    import simplejson
ImportError: No module named simplejson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/flasker/killerfees/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kf import app
  File "/home/flasker/killerfees/kf/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from kf import views
  File "/home/flasker/killerfees/kf/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    import simplejson
ImportError: No module named simplejson
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22527] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22527)
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22522] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-01-26 22:53:32 +0000] [22522] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

sys.path:

```
['/home/flasker/killerfees', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

imports from views.py:

```
from kf import app, mail, model, va, pdfgen
from flask import render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, jsonify, make_response, g, flash, abort
from flask.ext.mail import Message
import simplejson
```

Comment: does it successfully import any other non built in modules?

Comment: to help debug try adding right above it: `import sys`  `print(sys.path)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Yes, it imports flask, flask-core, and other modules, added sys.path to the bottom

Comment: Ok, I fixed it for the short term by using flasks built-in json function, and removing simplejson, and switching all simplejson to flask.json

Comment: how do you install it in virtualenv? are you sure it's actually installed there? Do you use requirements.txt ?

Comment: @Ashalynd I used: virtualenv env, then . env/bin/activate, then i used pip to install the requirements manually

Comment: when you create your virtualenv  you should set the flag --no-site-packages, this means it will not share packages at all.  I would be willing to bet your virtualenv site-packages directory did not have the package you're looking for.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, when I did pip install simplejson, i used --ignore-installed to insure the local env had the package required.  Not to mention, sys.path shows the std python library, which simplejson was set to.  BUt I will recreate the virtualenv, with this flag and see what happens

Comment: can you manually look in the site-packages folder of your python virtualenv and make sure it's there?